# How to make application default for image sharing in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

> Here is the scenario
>
> 1) I open some image from gallery and click on share button it display
>   application list to choose
>
> 2) When i choose my application from the
>   list it always open from launcher activity if my application is not in
>   background
>
> 3) When i select facebook instead on my application it
>   opens like this

[image]

> 4) When i see background runnig application facebook is displaying on
>   the gallary application like below image (facebook app is not open)

[image]

> but it won't happen same with my application my manifest code is 
>   below

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>         
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
              </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sharing activity jus need this intent filters. **Remove *action Main* from this - if you dont want to launch it from launcher icon**

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
```

You jus need following intent filters to make the activity capable of sharing/sending image

```
            <activity
                android:name=".ShareActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_share" >

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
```

Then the activity which deal the share functionality should handle the data

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

        // Get intent, action and MIME type
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
           if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
               Toast.makeText(ShareActivity.this,"share",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Handle single image being sent
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i did as you said but still same issue , my problem is why it opens splash screen if my application is not running and when choose my application from sharing list, otherwise if my application in background it will directly open from the main activity and i am able to get uri

Comment: like in my second screen shot you can see that facebook app is not open but sharing screen is displaying on gallery